# App crashes when trying to print contacts using Address Book API

Tags: swift

I have the following code to print the contacts:

```
let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as [ABRecord]
for person in people {
    println(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue())
}
```

The program always crashes after iterating the `people` array. The array has 6 elements of type `AnyObject`. Can this be a cast problem ?

The error I get is: `Thread_1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (code = EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe error happened in other places. I try below code and it works ok.

```
var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef? = extractABAddressBookRef(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil))
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, { success, error in
     if success {
         let people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as [ABRecord]
         for person in people {
              println(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue())
         }
     }
})
```